# APA Citation of Website With No Author Mentioned

Tags: citation-style

I get conflicting information about APA website citations from different sources. What is the best way to cite website documentation in APA style? For example, if I want to cite an announcement website about Apache Struts project releases (with no author given), do I cite it as:
Apache Struts Team. (2018). *Announcements 2018*. Retrieved from https://struts.apache.org/announce-2018.html

And in-text citation would be given like this?  Struts 2.3.36 was released as a "General Availability" release on October 15, 2018 (Apache Struts Team, 2018).

Comment: Do you not need to also include the date at which you have accessed the website?

Comment: @customcommander It looks like APA style to cite website doesn't require the date that website was accessed.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLOSURE:** I work for Mendeley as a software engineer. The reason I have used Mendeley is to show how it would cite this particular reference with this particular citation style using a tool familiar with academics and scholars.

---

Based on my findings, the citation would look like:

> Apache Struts Team. (2018). Announcements 2018. Retrieved March 28, 2019, from https://struts.apache.org/announce-2018.html

And the in-text citation would look like:

> (Apache Struts Team, 2018)

---

*Please find below the steps I took to produce this answer:*

1. I imported https://struts.apache.org/announce-2018.html using a Mendeley tool; I manually entered missing information in an attempt to construct a reference similar to yours:

   [image]
2. And this how the reference looks like in Mendeley:

   [image]
3. I can select this reference a copy/paste it using a citation style:

   [image]
4. The formatted citation will use this citation style:

   [image]
5. This is what you get when you paste it:

   > Apache Struts Team. (2018). Announcements 2018. Retrieved March 28, 2019, from https://struts.apache.org/announce-2018.html
6. Then I can use another Mendeley tool to produce an "in-text" citation: (using the same citation style as in step 3)

   [image]
7. Which gives me this in-text citation:

   > (Apache Struts Team, 2018)

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question indicates that there is no author mentioned, but in the body of the question, you imply that the author is a corporate body, i.e. the Apache Struts Team. This certainly counts as an author.

In their [blog about style](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/11/how-to-cite-something-you-found-on-a-website-in-apa-style.html), the APA say that you should cite information found on the web in the same format as you cite information found in a physical print form for the same kind of content. They provide a template that uses author, date, title, and source:

> Author, A. (date). Title of document [Format description]. Retrieved from https://URL
>
> In text: (Author, year)

They also provide alternate templates for citations when you are missing one of the four pieces of information.

Regarding a website with no author mentioned, the APA say in their [FAQs](https://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/web-page-no-author):

> #### How do you reference a web page that lists no author?
>
> When there is no author for a web page, the title moves to the first position of the reference entry:
>
> **Example:**
>   All 33 Chile miners freed in flawless rescue. (2010, October 13). Retrieved from http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/39625809/ns/world_news-americas/
>
> Cite in text the first few words of the reference list entry (usually the title) and the year. Use double quotation marks around the title or abbreviated title.: ("All 33 Chile Miners," 2010).