# In IEEE format, How to cite a website when no author name is given?

Tags: citations, citation-style, ieee

**Problem**

I have to cite [this](https://www.rsph.org.uk/about-us/news/instagram-ranked-worst-for-young-people-s-mental-health.html) webpage. However, no author name is given there.

**What I have found?**

[This](https://apastyle.apa.org/learn/faqs/web-page-no-author) and [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/apa-citation-of-website-with-no-author-mentioned) have referred, when we do not find author name, the title moves to the first position of the reference entry. However, it is in the APA style. From [this one](https://libguides.nps.edu/citation/ieee#website), I understand that I should use organization / Company name regarding the website, when no author name is mentioned.

**My Question**

In IEEE format, Should I use organization name in citation of a webpage when no author name is given? Citation of [this webpage](https://www.rsph.org.uk/about-us/news/instagram-ranked-worst-for-young-people-s-mental-health.html) in IEEE format is given below as an example:

RSPH Authority . "Instagram ranked worst for young people’s mental health." https://www.rsph.org.uk/about-us/news/instagram-ranked-worst-for-young-people-s-mental-health.html (Accessed Sept. 28, 2019)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In IEEE format, Should I use organization name in citation of a webpage when no author name is given?

Yes. It seems pretty reasonable that the organisation is the author of the content and holder of its copyright. This should apply to all citation styles and not just IEEE.

As an example, [the Victoria University library has a how-to webpage explaining this](http://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/ieeereferencing/webbaseddocument):

> If a publication is published by an organisation, association or a corporation, and there are no personal authors' names listed on the page, then list that institution as an author (this use is known as listing a corporate author, as opposed to listing a personal author). The corporate author may also be provided as the publisher of a source if the publisher's information is not listed on the page.